# Is $( \cos (t^3) , \sin(t^3) )$ a reparametrization of $( \cos(t) , \sin(t) )$?

Tags: calculus

Is $\beta(t) = ( \cos (t^3) , \sin(t^3) )$ a reparametrization of $\alpha(t) = ( \cos(t) , \sin(t) )$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$?

From the definition, a curve $\beta(t): J \subset \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is a reparametrization of a curve $\alpha(t): I \subset \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^n$ if there exist a diffeomorphism $f: I \to J$ such that

$$
\alpha(t) = \beta(f(t)), \quad \forall t \in I
$$

Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism $f(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$, this is easy to see from the fact that the inverse $f^{-1}: J \to I$ exist and is also differentiable.

Now, I was thinking that perhaps I could consider the function $f:\Bbb{R} \backslash \{0\} \to \Bbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ defined as $f(t) = t^{1/3}$, this would be a diffeomorphism such that

$$
\alpha(t) = \beta(f(t)), \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R} \backslash \{0\}
$$

Now, if there existed a diffeomorphism $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that

$$
\alpha(t) = \beta(g(t)) \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R}
$$

Then we would have that $f(t) = g(t)$ for all $t \neq 0$. Since $f,g$ are differentiable and the derivative of $f$ is continuous we would have that

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} g'(t) = \lim_{t \to 0} f'(t) = 0
$$

Which is a contradiction since we assumed $g$ is diffeomorphism, therefore $\beta$ is not a reparametrization of $\alpha$.

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct, specially the last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how is it that you get a contradiction from the fact that $\lim_{t \to 0} g'(t) = \lim_{t \to 0} f'(t) = 0$. But, in fact, $\beta$ is not a reparametrisation of $\alpha$. That's so because $\beta'(0)=0$, whereas, $\alpha'$ has no zeros.